# How to back-calculate the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of beta function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

Modify from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188190/how-to-integrate-int-01xa1-xbdx), if my beta distribution has the following prior:

$$f_{\Theta }(\theta )= a\theta (1-\theta )^2,\textrm{for}\ \theta\in [0,1],$$

and knowing that:

$$\int\limits_0^1\theta^\alpha (1-\theta )^{\beta }\,  d\theta =\frac{\alpha !\,  \beta !}{(\alpha +\beta +1)!}$$

How do I back-calculate the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?  Thanks.

Comment: $f_{\Theta }(\theta )$ looks rather like a probability distribution depending on parameter $\theta$ and the question could be rather to find $a$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are already given. Just look.

Comment: I was hoping to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to calculate $a$.

Comment: Look at the exponents and note that $\theta = \theta^1$. Then plug these two exponents into the given formula for the integral.

Comment: So $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 2$?

Comment: You got it! :-)

Comment: My lord, you saved the day!  xD